Composition of vectorvalued functions
Suppose I have two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and that I want to compute $g(f(x,y))$. As an example, let's take $f(x,y)=(x+y, x-y)$ and $g(x,y)=(y^2,x^2)$. Then, $g(f(1,2))=(1,9)$.
I have tried implementing this in Mathematica as follows.
f[x_, y_] = {x + y, x - y}
g[x_, y_] = {y^2, x^2}
g[f[1, 2]]
But instead of getting {1, 9} back, I'm getting g[{3, -1}]
If I change my definitions to f[{x_, y_}] = {x + y, x - y} and g[{x_, y_}] = {y^2, x^2}, I get the right thing back, but then I have to call g[f[{1, 2}]].
Is there a way to make this work without having to pass in curly braces to g[f[  ]]?

You must use SetDelayed (:=) in your function definitions
Without the curly braces:
Clear[f, g]

f[x_, y_] := {x + y, x - y}

g[x_, y_] := {y^2, x^2}


g @@ f[1, 2]


{1, 9}

Also:
Clear[f, g]

f[x_, y_] := {x + y, x - y}

Because Power is a listable function:
g[x_] := Reverse[x^2]


g[f[1, 2]]


{1, 9}

Or
g @ f[1, 2]


{1, 9}


Thank you. This seems to be the closest to what I want, with @@. (The power is not really part of what I want to do, it was just to have something relatively simple to work with)

Thank you for the acceptance :)


but then I have to call g[f[{1, 2}]]

Why is that a problem? It's really the "right" way to do it. With your current definitions, your functions each map two arguments to a single output value (that happens to be a pair). So you're not going to be able to compose them directly.
But if you must, @eldo's suggestion of g @@ f[1, 2] is the most straightforward. But just for variety's sake...
(Apply[g]@*f)[1, 2]

...also works.
And you could also overload your functions:
f[x_, y_] := f[{x, y}];
f[{x_, y_}] := {x + y, x - y};
g[x_, y_] := g[{x, y}];
g[{x_, y_}] := {y^2, x^2};


The problem is code clarity. What I want to express is a function of two variables that has an output in R^2. Yes, it works with overloads, etc., but the goal is to have something natural to work with that does the right thing.

{#2^2, #1^2} & @@ {#1 + #2, #1 - #2} & @@ {1, 2}

(* {1, 9} *) 

Or
Function[{x, y}, {y^2, x^2}] @@ Function[{x, y}, {x + y, x - y}] @@ {1, 2}

(* {1, 9} *)

Or, perhaps:
Composition[{#2^2, #1^2} &, Sequence @@ {#1 + #2, #1 - #2} &][1, 2]

(* {1, 9} *)

In addition:
{#2^2, #1^2} &[#1 + #2, #1 - #2] &[1, 2]

(* {1,9} *)

